# Apply different validation rules to the same complex property type in model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

This should have come up like a million times by now, but I can't seem to find anything solid that I like.

Please, consider

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
}
```

which appears twice in my view model

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public Person MainContact { get; set; }
    public Person AltContact { get; set; }
}
```

Main contact is always required.  Alternative contact is not required, but if anything is entered it should validate the entry. If I was to have 2 different Contact classes, they would be described like this:

```
public class MainContact
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    string LastName { get; set; }

    string Position { get; set; }
}

public class AltContact
{
    [StringLength(50)]
    string FirstName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    string LastName { get; set; }

    string Position { get; set; }
}
```

But, I don't want to have 2 different Contact classes with the exactly same properties.

I would like one set of validations applied to one instance of Person class and another set of validations applied to a different instance of the same Person class. The solution also has to work with the client side validation with unobtrusive js turned on.

**UPDATE 1**:  Added string Position to Person and Contact classes.

**UPDATE 2**:  Thank you all for your inputs.  Given time constraints and old UI requirements, I ended up with having 2 separate classes.  However, I personally like  Erik Funkenbusch's alternative approach from comments below.  If I'll run into a similar situation in the future, I will push for the List of objects and the "Add New Bla" button solution.  I think that's the way to go.

Comment: Short answer is you cant. You need different view models,one with the attributes ad the other without.

Comment: @StephenMuecke - Why not?  Any materials I can read on this?  Thanks.

Comment: Validations are all or nothing. One option would be to modify your model in include a (say) `bool IsMandatory` and then use a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[RequiredIfTrue("IsMandatory")]` or similar conditional attribute to your properties (and set `IsMandatory = true` on the `MainContact` property) but that would not require all properties of `AltContact` to be required if only one property is filled in

Comment: Another option would be to have an 'Add Alt Contact' button that dynamically adds the `AltContact` controls using ajax (and reparse the validator in the success callback). If the `AltContact` is not added, then it will be `null` when you submit and it will pass validation. If you do add it, then `AltContact` will not be `null` and validation will fail unless all required properties are completed.

Answer (score 0):

As the Null property answer doesn't seem to be working for you, I would suggest the following model then :

```
 public class MainContact: BaseContact
    {
        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public override string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public override string LastName { get; set; }

    }

    public class BaseContact
    {
        [StringLength(50)]
        public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public virtual string LastName { get; set; }

        string Position { get; set; }
    }
```

and then make the MainModel like so :

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public MainContact MainContact { get; set; }
    public BaseContact AltContact { get; set; }
}
```

You still need to have two different models, but you get the benefit of sharing the common elements through inheritance.

Comment: I might have oversimplified my problem for the sake of this question.  With UPDATE 1 in place, would your solution still work?

Comment: Yeah, the only thing we have done is make the altContact optional on the outer model. If the altContact is there on the model then it must conform to the attribute validates if not, then no validation.

Comment: I just tried your example, the unobtrusive JS validation does not work.  Also, in this case, I don't see a way of hooking up a custom Error Message to either First and Last name fields.

Comment: Was altContact null on the model? It definitely works.

Comment: I need it to work with client side unobtrusive JS validation as well. Sticking [Required] on a complex type doesn't do anything on the client side, because it wants to look at and validate individual fields.
Even if we forget the client side validation, it still doesn't work server side on submit.  If you don't enter any values for a complex type, the object itself gets a new instance with individual fields being NULL.

Comment: @Dimskiy - The way you would solve this normally is to make the optional object dynamically added and removed.  So, you only have the the Primary Contact in your HTML, then you have an "Add Contact" button which inserts the second set of contact information fields, thus when you submit with only a single object only the first one is validated, and the second is ignored.  When you add the second, then both are validated.  See this article: http://www.mattlunn.me.uk/blog/2014/08/how-to-dynamically-via-ajax-add-new-items-to-a-bound-list-model-in-asp-mvc-net/

Comment: You should be able to adapt it from a list to a single object.  Or better yet, just make both contacts a list in your model and use the dynamic list as-is.  This is actually a cleaner approach, and doesn't confuse the user about what is and isn't optional.

Comment: As the Client Side Validation doesn't seem to be working for you I have canned the original answer and proposed going down an inheritance path.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch this is the way I have used it historically.  This doesn't seem to work for the OP, so I have proposed a different solution.

Comment: @RichLinnell - What is the way you've used it?  If you have fields on the page, it's going to create the Person object, so the required condition will be met, even if the fields at empty.  I suggest you try it yourself, because your solution as is doesn't work the way you suggest it will.  The only way to make the altContact null is to not have it's fields be on the page.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch I have used it, like you point out, in a collection, which is empty if the Alternative isn't required, but is added if needed.  I realise that this is different to the way the OP wants to use it so I have proposed he sticks with 2 separate models, albeit leveraging inheritance to avoid duplication as much as possible.